# Range.Find Function

Tags: excel, vba

Using the Range.Find Method doesn't work for the file name.
The Range DocPresent is always "Nothing"

I am processing multiple Excel Sheets and want to track which ones I already processed. To make sure I don't process the Sheet again when I rerun the Macro

```
Dim wbname1 As String
wbname1 = ActiveWorkbook.Name

Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = wbname1


Dim DocPresent As Range
Set DocPresent = Range("A1:A1000").Find(What:=wbname1)
```

I am expecting the range to return the correct range if it finds the respective cell.

Comment: You have not specified a workbook and -sheet for your range objects, so now VBA refers to the active workbook and -sheet. If that's not what you want to look in, you won't find what you're looking for. Good practise is to use [With...End With](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement)

Answer (score 2):

Note that `Range("A1").End(xlDown)` might end up below `A1000` but your `.Find` is only looking before `A1000`.

So either use the whole column `Range("A:A").Find…` or find the last used cell `Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Find…`

And specify a workbook and worksheet for **all** your ranges!

```
Dim wbname1 As String
wbname1 = ActiveWorkbook.Name

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")

ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = wbname1

Dim DocPresent As Range
Set DocPresent = ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Find(What:=wbname1, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

Note that `ThisWorkbook` points to the workbook this code is running in. But `ActiveWorkbook` points to the workbook that has focus (is on top) at the moment the code is running. `ActiveWorkbook` can easily change by a user's click but `ThisWorkbook` is always the same.

Also note that the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find) has a `LookAt` parameter that should **always** be specified `xlWhole` or `xlPart`. Otherwise VBA uses the one that was used last either by VBA or by user interface. So you never know which one VBA is going to use, therefore always specify it.

According to the comment below you should check if your `Find` method was successfull before you use `DocPresent` so you don't run into an error:

```
If Not DocPresent Is Nothing Then
    'do your stuff using DocPresent 
Else
    MsgBox "'" & wbname1 & "' was not found.", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Adding on Pᴇʜ answer, after `Set DocPresent` you should make a check `If DocPresent= Nothing Then` to avoid errors if what you are looking for is not exist.

Comment: @Error1004 You are right, added it to my answer. But note that you need to use `Is` to check that `DocPresent Is Nothing` a equal sign `=` does not work.

Comment: `If DocPresent= Nothing` is the check, not the actual code :-)